# $\alpha=\mathbb{P}(\text{test rejects }H_0|H_0)$ (definition of size of test)

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Size_(statistics)):

> In statistics, the size $\alpha$ of a test is the probability of falsely rejecting the null hypothesis/making a type $1$ error. For a simple hypothesis,
> $$\alpha=\mathbb{P}(\text{test rejects }H_0|H_0).$$

I am a bit confused because of the last equation. I thought that $H_0$ should be imagined to be a proposition that is either true or false independently of the outcome of the experiment. In particular, $H_0$ is not an [event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_(probability_theory)), is it? So the notation (which suggests that $\alpha$ is a conditional probability) is misleading, isn't it? I assume that the author meant that $\alpha=\mathbb{P}(\text{test rejects }H_0)$ if $H_0$ is true and otherwise the size is simply not defined (or equal to zero, as no type 1 error can occur) - is that correct?

This is not a rant, I just want to make sure that I understand the definition correctly.

Comment: I learned that Size of test = $\alpha=\mathbb{P}(\text{test rejects }H_0|H_0$ true). Does this make more sense?

Comment: @AdamRubinson It doesnt really make a difference. The point is that your definition suggests that $H_0$ can be either true or false (i.e. the truth value is a random variable), but I thought that this is usually not the case?

Comment: Yes you are right, the notation is misleading. Moreover, it is not a very general definition, so we don't use it regardless

Comment: $H_0$ is a truth statement such as, "$p = 0.5$". And the alternative hypothesis, $H_1,$ could be (for example): "$p> 0.5$" if it's a one-tailed test. I don't think I understand what it is that you don't understand, but basically the "size" and "power" of tests make some sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose one has a family of probability measures $\mathcal P$. Let $\mathcal P_0 \sqcup \mathcal P_1$ be a partition of $\mathcal P$. A test $T$ is a statistic taking values in $\{0,1\}$. One way to evaluate the performance of a test is its size $\alpha$: $$\alpha \overset{\text{def}}{=} \sup_{P\in \mathcal P_0} P(T=1)$$ It is usually intractable to compute $\alpha$, and when people talk about the size of a test, they really mean the limiting size of the test. Namely, $T_n = T_n(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ and $$\alpha \overset{\text{def}}{=}\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{P\in \mathcal P_0}P(T_n = 1)$$

Comment: This definition falls from the sky for me. Where did the hypothesis $H_0$ go? What is the motivation for considering a family of probability measures?

Comment: $H_0$ is identified with $\mathcal P_0$, i.e. $H_0: P\in \mathcal P_0$. The goal of hypothesis testing and (more generally statistical inference) is to infer the unknown probability measure $P$ (which generates the data)

Comment: Thank you. However the $\alpha$ associated to an arbitrary $T$ does not have a clear interpretation anymore, does it?  Or how is $T$ helping us to infer the unknown probability measure?

Comment: If $T=i$, you infer $P\in \mathcal P_i$

Comment: With $T=i$ you mean $\forall\omega\in\Omega: T(\omega)=i$?

Comment: No, $T$ is a statistic, i.e. function of the data $T_n = T_n(X_1,\dots,X_n)$. So I mean if $T$ has the realization $1$, then one infers the data was generated by a measure in $\mathcal P_1$. And if realization $0$, one infers the data was generated by a measure in $\mathcal P_0$. (This last sentence is an oversimplification. Since statisticians are complicated people, we instead say "failed to reject $H_0$," which is philosophically more correct, though is beyond mathematics.)

Comment: I am confused. I thought that the $X_i$ are random variables on $\Omega$ and hence the composition $T_n=T(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is also a random variable?

Comment: Yes, you are right. So I don't see your confusion? Why you say $T(\omega) = i$ for all $\omega$? I am just saying that if we observe $T(\omega) = 1$, then we infer $P\in \mathcal P_1$

Comment: I see, thank you for the confirmation.

Comment: "So I mean if $T$ has the realization 1, then one infers the data was generated by a measure in $P_1$. And if realization 0, one infers the data was generated by a measure in $P_0$." - How do you know that this is a sensible procedure/that $T$ is a good test? With the definition from Wikipedia, it is clear that a good test has a small $\alpha$ (as $\alpha$ is precisely the probability of a type 1 error). But with your definition the interpretation of $\alpha$ is not clear to me.

Comment: It's pretty clear to me that $\alpha$ here is also the probability of a type 1 error, as long as the null is simple. If the null is composite, then it is the "worst case" probability of a type 1 error

Comment: "...as long as the null is simple." - I.e. as long as $P_0$ contains exactly one measure?

Comment: Yes; i just looked at Wikipedia. What I wrote is identical to theirs up to a change of notation, so I dont see where your objection is

Comment: "so I dont see where your objection is" - Let $P$ be the unknown measure that we try to infer. Isn't the probability of a type 1 error equal to $P(T=1)$ if $P\in P_0$ and equal to $0$ otherwise? This is clearly not equivalent to your definition of $\alpha$.

Comment: The point of statistics is that you are working without (total) knowledge of the data generating process. From this viewpoint, what I've written is perfectly okay

Comment: Okay, I see what you are saying now. No, $\alpha$ is not the probability of making a type 1 error. It is exactly what I have written, and this is the convention used in statistics. When we say that $\alpha$ is the probability of a type 1 error, we are being imprecise/uncareful, since as you point out, said probability is zero if the true measure is in $\mathcal P_1$

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation! This feels a little bit paradoxical though. If we already know whether the true measure is in $P_0$, then we do not need the test. But if we don't know, then we can not tell whether the test is useful or not (since the value of $\alpha$ is meaningless if the true measure does not happen to be in $P_0$). How do you cope with this?

Comment: See minimax risk, it is essentially analogous.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the keyword!